# Eclipse 3.4 GWT 1.6 project - how to reference source from other projects?

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I've got a GWT 1.6 project in Eclipse 3.4 and am trying to reference source from another (**non-GWT**) project in my workspace.  I've added the project to my build path, but I can't run the application in hosted mode.  When I do, I get a "no source code is available" error.

I've done some searching and reading and have tried a few things that others have suggested (including creating a jar from the dependent project and linking to it), but frankly nothing has worked.

If you're actually doing this, could you please help me out with a simple step-by-step setup?  I'd really appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have 2 Eclipse Projects. One is gwt project and one is not. Here's the directory structure that works for me:

```
workspace
-- gwt-project
   -- src/main/java
      -- com.gwt.GwtProjectModule
         -- GwtProjectModule.gwt.xml
-- non-gwt-project
   -- src/main/java
      -- com.nongwt.package.that.contains.source.you.need
         -- nongwt.gwt.xml
      -- com.nongwt.package.that.contains.source.you.need.client
```

nongwt.gwt.xml tells gwt to look inside "client" package, here's what it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 1.7.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='nongwt'>
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
    <source path="client" />
</module>
```

GwtProjectModule.gwt.xml can then inherit source code from nongwt. Here's the relevant line from inside GwtProjectModule.gwt.xml:

```
<inherits name="com.nongwt.package.that.contains.source.you.need.nongwt" />
```

Make sure you include non-gwt-project inside gwt-project's classpath in eclipse. It's the normal drill; right click on gwt-project, choose properties, choose "Java Build Path", click "Projects" tab, and "non-gwt-project"

Or, instead of including non-gwt-project in gwt-project's classpath as a project reference, you can also jar the contents of non-gwt--project, ensure that you include the source in the jar, and then include the jar in gwt-project's classpath.

Good Luck!

Comment: Old question and answer but still the only place I've found this explained properly. Everywhere else gives part answers like the others here. Thanks.

Comment: what is in the .client package of the nongwt project? Is that just a placeholder that gwt looks for? why do you need the inherits tag in that nongwt.gwt.xml?

Comment: Eclipse Neon, GWT 2.8 this does not work and needs a small fix. Go to Run configuration>Classpath>Advanced>Add Folder>NonGWTProject/src . This is because Eclipse adds project/bin to classpath and GWT wants project/src.

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is quite old but as I spent quite a lot of time on this issue and finally found the way to do it, I thought I might share the answer :

once you've created your launch configuration, open it run>run configurations...
go to classpath tab and select user entries. add advanced>folder and select the source folder of your other module project. If as me you've separated the module conf file in a src/main/resources folder you have to add it as well.

should work.

Comment: Found/understood your answer after spending 5 hours and then figuring it out myself. Upvote.

Answer (score 1):

The client-side code in your GWT project (the classes under the client package) can't reference any classes that aren't in a GWT module.

If you've got code in another project that you want to reference from client code in your GWT project, you need to:

- Make sure it's all "GWT safe", which means it doesn't reference any JRE classes that aren't emulated by GWT (http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/RefJreEmulation.html), or reference any classes that reference JRE classes not emulated
- Make sure all referenced classes are within a GWT module. This means putting a MyOtherProject.gwt.xml file in your other project, and all the referenced classes must be under a client subpackage
- Make your GWT project inherit from the other project. So add the following to your GWT project's gwt.xml module file:

> <inherits name='com.yourCompany.otherProject.MyOtherProject' />

Comment: Yeah... when I try it that way is when barfs finding the entry point.  If I add the non-GWT project (containing a gwt module file) from my GWT project, it won't run.  If I export a jar from that same dependent project and include it in my GWT application, it all runs ok.

Comment: Regarding the entry point. Did you check the Google -> Web Toolkit properties in the eclipse preferences. It's possible the specific gwt.xml is added to the Entry Point module list. Removing the file from the list should make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Boden: add the following to your module file

```
<source path=""></source>
```

in addition to your other sources, eg:

```
<source path=""></source>
<source path="com.acme.otherpackage"></source>
```

then the compiler won't complain.

Atleast that's how I solved it. Not sure if using path="" allows inclusion of everything, I'm assuming it's the default value when no sources are specified.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fantastic solution of your problem proposed by Sven Buschbeck (must a norwegian, lol!), worked for me!

When work­ing on sev­eral large scale projects (in Eclipse), it’s con­ve­nient and of course more effi­cient to share and reuse code via com­mon libraries. While those are in an early stage they need to be changed a lot and there­fore it’s handy to link projects in instead of cre­at­ing new jars each time the library has been updated.
Unfor­tu­nately, this stan­dard approach for Java devel­op­ment in Eclipse does not work that straight for­ward as with plain old Java projects, it requires three steps in total:

1. Link the library project to all rel­e­vant projects (“Project
   Pref­er­ences” -> “Java Build Path” -> “Projects” -> “Add…”)
2. Then, add the client-side code of the library (by adding it as a
   mod­ule.) There­fore, edit the gwt.xml of your appli­ca­tion and add
   for exam­ple 
   where Super­Lib is the file name of the gwt.xml file in you library
   project and before that is the pack­age it lies in.
3. Add the code to the project by link­ing a source folder.
   Unfor­tu­nately, this is required if you do not want to write an Ant
   script to com­pile your appli­ca­tion. (If you pre­fer Ant check
   this out) I don’t like the idea of using such a script because if
   you for­get to run it each time you make changes, you will end up in
   confusion—let’s go for the con­ve­nient, auto­matic way then.

   - Add a folder to your appli­ca­tion project; open the “advanced” sec­tion in the folder cre­ation dia­log, select “Link to alter­nate loca­tion” and pick the source folder (usu­ally “src”) of your library project. (Hint: if you work within a team using a ver­sion­ing sys­tem, you can cre­ate a vari­able for that folder and use this instead. This way, each of your col­leagues can put the library project in a dif­fer­ent folder and accom­mo­date for that by adjust­ing the vari­able :) )
   - Right click the folder, “Build Path” -> “Use as Source Folder”. Done.
     Sur­pris­ingly, the GWT plu­gin for Eclipse does not honor the project link­ing, thus all the ref­er­ences need to be made explicit or you will end up with lots of the fol­low­ing: ClassNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

GWT doesn't know about that other code because it is not in the client directory of your project.  You need to add the source path for the other code to the .gwt.xml file.  Just added it to the xml as follows

```
<source path="common" />
```

**common** is the directory where the extra code is for this example.

Check out the **XML Element Reference** section of this [doc](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModuleXml)

Comment: I've tried that.  It then pukes saying that it can't find the entry point class (well, it just says it can't find type xxx.xxx.MyEntryPointClassType).  The class is there.  Everything works if I remove the dependent project and references.

Comment: You also need to make sure the client directory is added as a source path in the .gwt.xml file.  For some reason if you add a custom source path the default client source path is not seen. So basically you need both the <source path="common" />
and the <source path="client" />
to get things working

Comment: That's not working either... 

The only way I've gotten it to work thus far is to create a .gwt.xml module in the dependent project, create a jar from the source folder, and then "inherit" the module in the gwt project.  This is far from ideal but sorta works.

Comment: I've tried making including the project, I've tried linking source, I've tried everything I can think of.  I don't believe this is possible without using a jar.

Answer (score 0):

In your gwt project, go to properties, Java build path, source, click "link source" and point to your non-gwt project source package that you wish to include.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Found a eclipse fix. Run config > Classpath > Advanced > Add folder > otherproject/src .

Reason: Eclipse adds the bin folders of exported projects. GWT needs the src folders.

Elaborating on my comment.

I am using gwt 2.8 on Eclipse Neon, Java 1.8.0_92. Referring to another project in eclipse fails to launch devmode, because it cannot find the source for referred files from the other project.

What worked:

Switched to 'ant devmode' completely. Made the following changes to build.xml:

```
<target name="gwtc" ...>
    <java ...>
      <classpath>
        <pathelement location="src"/>
        <pathelement location="../otherproject/src"/><!-- Added -->
...
...
  <target name="devmode" ...>
    <java ...>
      <classpath>
        <pathelement location="src"/>
        <pathelement location="../otherproject/src"/><!-- Added -->
```

Now do a production build with 'ant' or start devmode with 'ant devmode'.

Other things I noticed

1. Using the method in the accepted answer, otherproject/src/foo.gwt.xml is picked up (complains if not available), and static values from classes are picked up. Nothing else is. Very weird.
2. I understand that the DevMode/gwtc executables pick up sources from their class path. So all that is needed is for eclipse to add referred projects to their class path. I was not able to achieve this but this seems possible. FIXED see top.