# Referencing An Eclipse Java Project from a GWT Project

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I have a java project already in eclipse, and I need to use the classes there in the *server* code of my GWT project, also in eclipse. I have a package, let's call it `com.example` with lots of subpackages.

I followed the instructions here:
[Eclipse 3.4 GWT 1.6 project - how to reference source from other projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951926/eclipse-3-4-gwt-1-6-project-how-to-reference-source-from-other-projects) by defining the following file in the root package

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 1.7.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='example'>
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
    <source path="*" />
</module>
```

and in GWT XML file, I added

```
<inherits name="com.example" />
```

But I keep getting

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

for classes defined in `com.example`

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to reference classes for use on the server-side (i.e. not by GWT actually), then you don't need all that stuff. The GWT modules are only about client-side code to be processed by the DevMode and ultimately the GWT Compiler.

Comment: Thank you. But then any idea why I get the NoClassDefFoundError issue, since the GWT project is configured to have the original Java project in its build path.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar project setup, except I'm using get 2.3, and it works without problems. But I get warning messages as below;

```
 [WARN] Server class '<CLASS_IN_OTHER_PROJECT>' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
   [WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/workspace/<OTHER PROJECT>/src/' to the web app classpath for this session
For additional info see: file:/Downloads/gwt-2.3.0/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html
```

May be you are using an older version of gwt which does not have the above workaround put in place. You may check info mentioned in above warning message [here](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distro-source/core/src/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html).

At sum, it is stated that;

> All server classes and dependencies should to be placed in your war
>   directory: libraries (jars) should be placed in war/WEB-INF/lib/ and
>   classes that don't live in jars should be placed in
>   war/WEB-INF/classes/.

So I guess you won't have problems if you export your utility project (the one to which you depend for server side classes) as a jar file and drop it into war/WEB-INF/lib/ folder of your module.